# Конструктор с параметрами во множественном наследовании

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование, конструктор

Какой синтаксис объявления конструктора с параметрами при множественном наследовании?

Comment: А в учебнике не написано? Перечислить конструкторы базовых классов пробовали?

Comment: к сожалению не написано. НО как именно их перечислить? в каком порядке, в каком порядке параметры и тд

Comment: синтаксис объявления — в точности такой же как и при обычном наследовании... и даже такой же как без наследования... так что вопрос не особо понятен...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё практически так же как и при одиночном наследовании.

```
struct B1
{
    B1(int) {}
};

struct B2
{
    B2(double) {}
};

struct D : B1, B2
{
    D() : B1(42), B2(0.75) { }
};
```

При этом конструкторы базовых классов вызываются в том порядке, как выполнено наследование, а не как они записаны при вызове конструктора.

Comment: Вместо чисел B1(42) B2(0.75) структуре D могут стоять переменные?

Comment: @MarynaSaid ну Вы попробуйте, это быстрее будет, чем спросить и дождаться ответа.